# How do I get my $http request in my Angular service to be called during Jasmine+Karma unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

So, I am currently testing a function in AngularJS with Jasmine+Karma. I am trying to create an object and see whether or not it has successfully be added to the database. This function calls another asynchronous function which I cannot seem to account for in testing. I know it is never called, because I am not receiving anything back from it. No console logs, errors, or anything. As of now, I have a service called StoringService, that looks like:

```
myApp.service("StoringService", function($http){

    // Stores my object
    this.store = function(object,success,error){
        var request = {
            method: "post",
            url: "example.com",
            headers: {/*...*/},
            data: object.toJSON()
        };
        $http(request).then(
            function(response){
                console.log("Success! Yay!");
                success(response.data.url.script);
            },function(response){
                console.log("Error! Bummer...");
                error(response);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

The main controller that I am testing is my CreationController. This has a function called Submit that calls the above service. This works when I run my application, but doesn't seem to when I run my tests. The submit method (inside CreationController) looks something like this:

```
myApp.controller("CreationController", ["$scope","StoringService",
    function($scope,StoringService){

        $scope.newObject = new Object();
        $scope.successAlert = false; // changed by success() in StoringService
        $scope.errorAlert = false; // changed by error() in StoringService

        $scope.submit = function(){
            StoringService.store($scope.newObject,
                function(message){
                    console.log(message);
                },
                function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }
}]);
```

Finally, when I got to the Jasmine+Karma tests, I noticed that my objects were not being created, and with further inspection, that my StoringService working fine up until the actual $http request (line 11 in sample code). I'm not entirely sure how to trigger this action. This is currently, what my tests look like.

```
//creation_test.js
var scope, service;

describe('Creation Test', function(){
    originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;

    beforeEach(module('MyApplication'));
    beforeEach(inject($rootScope, $controller, $injector){

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        service = $injector.get('StoringService');

        $controller('CreationController',{
            $scope: scope,
            StoringService: service
        });
    }));

    // Fails but should pass
    it('should create an object',function(done){
        scope.newObject.name = "new_object";
        scope.newObject.data = "object data";
        scope.submit();
        setTimeout(function(){
            expect(scope.successAlert).toBe(true);
            expect(scope.errorAlert).toBe(false);
            done();
        },5000);
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVL = originalTimeout;
    });
);
```

I am not entirely sure why this isn't working or how exactly to fix it. The values for successAlert and errorAlert are never changed, which leads me to believe that the $http request is never called. I have been trying possible solutions from [here](http://angulartestingquickstart.com/testing-promise#sample-project), but so far, none have resolved the issue. I would really appreciate help solving this problem, and I would be extremely happy if anyone found a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to test? I don't see `CreationController` creating any object...

Comment: I am just trying to test if the object successfully made it to the database or not. I left that code out, because I didn't know if it was necessary. But a blank object would simply look like Object{name:"",data:"",timestamp:""}. Using a form, the user would fill in the fields for name and data and submit to the database.

Comment: The thing you're trying to do is e2e testing, and it is something that is usually doesn't have to be performed in Karma. Angular unit testing presupposes that no real requests are performed. There should be **two** tests - one for controller unit with mocked service, another for service unit with mocked $http response. Unit tests test single units, hence the name. They are not 'all-in-one' tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. Following test make sure you are calling the service method with args.

```
expect(loginService.authenticate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
          user: 'david@yahoo.com',
          pass: '123'
        });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/6xmCPm66QWRZyfo1v0h5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked your test. When unit testing we don't want to spend time calling the backend and that's why we need to mock the HTTP calls. As your `store` method returns a promise, we emulate this behavior in the unit test creating a deferred promise that we can control. Later you can `resolve` or `reject` the promise to test for success and error. I hope it helps.

```
describe('Controller: CreationController', function() {

  beforeEach(module('MyApplication'));

  var storingService;
  var deferred;
  // Mock services and spy on methods
  beforeEach(inject(function($q, StoringService) {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    storingService = StoringService;
    spyOn(storingService, 'store').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
  }));

  var CreationController;
  var scope;
  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    CreationController = $controller('CreationController', {
      $scope: scope,
      StoringService: storingService
    });
  }));

  it('should create an object', function() {
    scope.submit();
    scope.$apply(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
    });
    expect(scope.successAlert).toBe(true);
    expect(scope.errorAlert).toBe(false);
  });

);
```